# Program Creation for business

Tags: python-3.x

Not sure if this is the right place to post this question but my son directed me to this site. I'm looking for someone to develop a simple program for my business.  I am a veterinarian and am struggling with our electronic medical records system. I am looking for a program that would turn a number code into a word or statement in order to generate a physical exam. I would like to be able to circle numbered codes on a sheet and basically have these codes scanned or hand entered in so as a paragraph would be formed.  Ideally this would have to be a word document that could then be printed out. If anyone out can do this or point me in the direction of a site where I can hire a programmer to do this, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Your son was wrong. SO is not a programming-service. We help each other to solve problems with their code, but don't write new programs for you. That would be far too much work for free ;-)

Comment: Thanks for at least taking time to respond. If u read my post, I am trying to solve a problem and did not ask for anyone to write code for me for free. The word "hire" under most normal circumstances means a monetary exchange. If someone reading my post can develop said program, great, contact me and we can work out how to do such a program and you will get paid for it. If not, then I would appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction where I can hire(i.e. Pay)a programmer for this work. Sorry for any confusion☹️